# How to count difference of dates with given range in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

Suppose i have a table **leave_management** that contains two dates columns
**from** & **to** with dates **"2016-12-11" & "2016-12-18"**

Now i want those output for given input...

***1.***
**Input:** *From:* **"2016-12-7"** *& To:* **2016-12-10**

**output:** ***date difference*** is **0** (No overlap found)

***2.***
**Input:** *From:* **"2016-12-16"** *& To:* **2016-12-18**

**output:** ***date difference*** is **2** (this range fully overlap with table data)

***3.***
**Input:** *From:* **"2016-12-18"** *& To:* **2016-12-20**

**output:** ***date difference*** is **1** (this range overlap partially with table data)

here, formula of count **date difference** =  ***(difference between given dates - overlap count)***

I tried a query like this..

```
SELECT sum((DATEDIFF(from_date, to_date)) 
FROM `leave_management` s1 
WHERE s1.from_date <='2016-12-20' AND s1.to_date >='2016-12-18'
```

This only give perfect output for first two inputs. But for third input it failed to give expected output. Please help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us sample data in the form of an actual _table_, along with the output you expect and a description of the logic?

Comment: What do you mean by ":solve"?? Do you mean a row was output from the select? By "failed", do you mean you didn't get a row, or there was an incorrect result.

Comment: formula of date difference = (difference between given dates - overlap count). But my query only get date difference = difference between given dates. So i get first two input those are within range or not. but third input partially match so date difference won't give me right output. because here i can't implement overlap count.

Comment: i want those output for given input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT sum(DATEDIFF(greatest(from_date, '2016-12-18'), least(to_date, '2016-12-20')) 
FROM `leave_management` s1 
WHERE s1.from_date <='2016-12-20' AND s1.to_date >= '2016-12-18';
```

One caveat is that you might need to add/subtract one day from the constants, depending on whether the end dates count as overlaps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. sum((DATEDIFF(greatest(from_date,'"+startDate+"'), least(to_date,'"+endDate+"'))*-1)+1) in my case.....Thanks again.

Comment: you also need to check that diff > 0 before doing the sum because case#1 will get negative diff using this query.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ . . . The `where` should prevent any negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the peroid_diff function of mysql to determine the difference

```
SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(from,to) Diff_months table1;
```

Refer this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff

Comment: this is not what the SO is about.

Comment: thank you @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, It very hard to understand the question and answer it without any sample data. Hence a general answer to guide the person to achieve his objective